# Microsoft user authentication on OneNote app?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy-note-4, microsoft-onenote

Everything on my Galaxy Note4 is up to date and working fine. No dice in attempting to troubleshoot so far with a few of the usual suspects - update OS and app software, clear app data & cache.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Microsoft has OneNote integration with the OneDrive app. In my case, authenticating through OneDrive before attempt to authenticate in OneNote worked, as suggested [in page 3 here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_onenote-mso_amobile/cant-sign-in-to-onenote-for-android/ff1eb765-55ef-470d-8368-c87fcd18d68b?page=3).